# How to enable DELIVERY_ATTEMPT header from consumer side in KAFKA?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have an spring boot kafka consumer application. So as per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#deliveryAttemptHeader) added `factory.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true);` in below and still not able to receive the deliveryAttempt header in consumer record at the kafka listener. What am I missing? **What changes do I need to get DeliveryAttempt Header at the consumer side?**

```
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory) {

        final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(testErrorHandler);
        factory.setConcurrency(10);

        factory.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true);

    

return factory;
}
```

ErrorHandler:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.CommonErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TestErrorHandler implements CommonErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleRecord(Exception thrownException, ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
            MessageListenerContainer container) {

        LogFactory.getLog(getClass()).error("'handleRecord' is not implemented by this handler", thrownException);
    }

}
```

In the above class, I have implemented CommonErrorHander(which extends DeliveryAttemptAware class internally).

Consumer:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class DataConsumer {

    
    @KafkaListener(topics = { "topic1" }, groupId = "test-group-1", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listenTestEvents(final ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> message) {

        log.info("Received TestEvent message :{}, headers: {}", message, message.headers());

        if (true) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      group-id: test-group-1
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

AppConfig:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;

import com.tmobile.retrykafkaconsume.kafka.TestErrorHandler;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private TestErrorHandler testErrorHandler;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Integer, String>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory) {

        final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(testErrorHandler);
        factory.setConcurrency(10);

        factory.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true);

        return factory;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Gary Russell Can you please suggest here.

Comment: There is no need to ping me; I get notifications of all new questions tagged with [tag:spring-kafka].

Comment: @Gary Russell Sure, Won't ping again, Have added all the required code. Kindly let me know anything needed. I want to use common errorhandler as my retry mechanism instead of retrytemplate/errorhandler since they are deprecated. But I could not find atleast one example over internet of it and spent 6 hours continuously on it. Kindly help.

Comment: Use the `DefaultErrorHandler` with a suitably configured `BackOff` and recoverer (such as the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`). https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#default-eh

Answer (score 1):

The error handler must implement `DeliveryAttemptAware`; see `FailedRecordProcessor` which is a super class of `DefaultErrorHandler`.

Show your `testErrorHandler` code.